# adding validation to models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to add some validation to my rails app. Im using Postgresql. I've created a post table and a user table. Each user can have multiple posts and each post can have multiple users. However, each post can have only one category(another table). What do I need to add to the model?

Comment: Is there some reason the answer isn't "use `Post belongs_to :category`"?

Comment: Do I also need to add Category belongs_to :Post?

Comment: This is very basic and covered in the [Active Record Associations guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It would be common to use `Category has_many :posts`, although you *could* alternatively use `Category has_one :post`. It depends on your business requirements. You would *not* use, however, `Category belongs_to :post`. Also note that you use `:post` and not `:Post`.

Comment: Sounds great! Thank you.

Comment: BTW, what version of rails are you using? This can make a difference.

Comment: I am using rails 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do, simply:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  category_id      :integer
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

...and...

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

Because you are using rails 6, `belongs_to` will enforce the presence of a valid `category_id`. No further validation is required. If you want `category_id` to be optional, then do something more like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  category_id      :integer
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
end
```